# Removing text when onSelectedChange Occurs

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am just wondering if anyone could give me indication as to how to remove a piece of text if a statement is not satisfied after `onSelectedChange` event.

My code,

```
protected void currency_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (stm_currency.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lblResults.Text = "" +
        stm_merchant.SelectedItem.Text + " statement for " +
        stm_month.SelectedItem.Text  + " " +
        stm_year.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    else 
    {
        lblResults.Text.Remove(0);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to clear all the text from the lblResults? Then `lblResults.Text = string.Empty;`If not then explain what you want to remove from lblResults

Comment: in addition to the answers and above comment, you should check to see if the label needs invoked first...         delegate void setLabelText(string s);
        public void invokeSetLabelText(string s)
        {
            if (this.lblResults.InvokeRequired)
            {
                setLabelText d = new setLabelText(invokeSetLabelText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { s });
            }
            else
            {
                lblResults.Text = s;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line of code

```
lblResults.Text = "";
```

It would set it to be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The remove method **returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in the current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.**

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You should use `lblResults.Text = "";` or `lblResults.Text = string.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the label needs invoked first.

```
delegate void setLabelText(string s);
public void invokeSetLabelText(string s)
{
    if (this.lblResults.InvokeRequired)
    {
        setLabelText d = new setLabelText(invokeSetLabelText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { s });
    }
    else
        lblResults.Text = s;
}

protected void currency_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (stm_currency.SelectedItem != null)
        invokeSetLabelText(string.Format("{0} statement for {1} {2}", 
            stm_merchant.SelectedItem.Text,
            stm_month.SelectedItem.Text, 
            stm_year.SelectedItem.Text));
    else
        invokeSetLabelText(string.Empty);
}
```